# Android studio canary 5 update error

Tags: android

Error:(249, 5) duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''
Error:(249, 5) resource previously defined here

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:

Comment: Same for me on canary 7

Comment: Happening for me when I try to upgrade to the 26.X.X support libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding in your gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to update to last version before disable `AAPT2`.

Comment: @Kevinrob Disable AAPT2 it is a simple workaround :)  this is the problem when uses a canary version

Answer (score 14):

I guess you implemented an attr.xml file with a line `<attr name="font">`. Since Android 8.0 comes with a new [feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) called 'Fonts in XML' this might be the reason for your Error. You could change the name of the attribute to e.g. `<attr name="font_name">` and probably in all your custom views and layout xmls, too. Or just use the new feature ;)

Comment: You are totally right, this should be the accepted answer.